# output hive data into csv with a where clause

Tags: sql, csv, hive, quotes, hiveql

I am currently trying to export Hive data to a csv file and CAN do it successfully until I have to add a where clause. For example, this works:

```
 hive -e 'select * from table' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.csv
```

But if I try this:

```
 hive -e 'select * from table where timestamp > '1-Aug-2013'' | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.csv
```

I get an error saying "Invalid table alias or column reference"

I think the issue could be due to the quotes around the date but I can't find a combination that works. Please help!

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you are using single quotes to wrap both the query and a string literal in the query. Try using double quotes to wrap the query instead, so that it is clear where the query ends.

```
hive -e "select * from table where timestamp > '1-Aug-2013'" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.csv
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Please see Hive Data Types [Link](https://cwiki.apache.org/Hive/languagemanual-types.html#LanguageManualTypes-Timestamps).

Timestamps were introduced in Hive 0.8.0.

```
Supported conversions:
Integer numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds
Floating point numeric types: Interpreted as UNIX timestamp in seconds
with decimal precision.
Strings: JDBC compliant java.sql.Timestamp format "YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS.fffffffff"
(9 decimal place precision)
```

According to it your timestamps format is not supported to hive.

Sample query is here :

```
 hive -e "select * from table where timestamp > '2013-08-19 00:00:00';exit;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g' > outputfile.csv
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I can adjust the where clause to use a full timestamp but do you have any suggestions on the issue with the quotes? Thanks again for the follow-up!

Comment: What data-type you are giving for timestamp. Datatype should be **bigint** for timestamp. please provide create table query and your modified select query. If possible please provide some sample data.

Comment: Use query like this:  **hive -e "select * from table where timestamp > '2013-08-19 00:00:00';exit;" | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > outputfile.csv**. If it now works please let us know.